# How can I return a generated excel file to download when link_to remote: true?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-5

I need to download a generated excel file in rails.

When the user click on link a excel file begins to be generated a formatted correctly in the backend and return as download file. When I set remote: true in link_to I expect the file to be downloaded but it doesn't return anything even if the process generating the excel file is over.

What can I do to return this file as download?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this without `remote: true` on the link/button. If you change your link/button to:

```
<%= link_to "Export as CSV", your_thing_path(@your_thing, format: "csv") %>
```

And add the following to your controller:

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.csv {
    send_data(render_to_string(layout: false),
    type: 'text/csv; charset=iso-8859-1; header=present',
    filename: "my_export.csv") 
  }
end
```

This will get you the same result as `remote: true`, and you can still queue off of the link click if you need presentation-level JavaScript in your view.

Comment: I have a send_data spreadsheet.string, :filename => "#{t 'controllers.prod_loop.stock'}.xls", :type =>  "application/vnd.ms-excel" in the controller, is it the same?

Comment: It should have the same effect. You might try simply removing the `remote: true` from the link and seeing if the download works. Adding `remote: true` will result in a `:js` response.

Comment: ok, but how can i do the page return the file staying in the same page, don't going to the link?

Comment: Might have to add some JavaScript to handle that. Perhaps `preventDefault()`. It would be helpful to have some code in your question